# How do i calculate characters in string without if conditions?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, count, strlen

I have the code example:

```
$str = '123456789101112131415';
  if(strlen($str) <9 )
  {
  echo "the string is  10";
  }
  elseif(strlen($str) > 9) {
  echo 'the string is  11';
  }
  elseif(strlen($str) > 21) {
  echo 'the string is  30';
  }
  elseif(strlen($str) > 31) {
  echo 'the string is  40';
  }
```

My problem is how do I sort out when the string is huge and not specified in the `if` conditions

Comment: `echo 'the string is ' . strlen($str);`

Comment: `echo 'the string is ' . (strlen($str) - strlen($str)%10)`

Comment: @miknik
not this thanks 
i just want in 9 after the other

Comment: You should use math.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate it!

1. call `strlen()`
2. divide by `10`
3. call `floor()` to remove decimals
4. multiply by `10`
5. check if less than `10`

Here is a battery of tests:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc283e1d6e5971946b3c970892c14b7fd76eb183))

```
$strings=[9=>'123456789',10=>'1234567890',11=>'12345678901',19=>'1234567890123456789',20=>'12345678901234567890',21=>'123456789012345678901'];
foreach($strings as $k=>$str){
    if(($group=floor(strlen($str)/10)*10)<10){  // use arithmetic to find the group, declare and check group in one step
        echo "$k => $str is not upto 10";
    }else{
        echo "$k => $str is in group $group";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
9 => 123456789 is not upto 10
10 => 1234567890 is in group 10
11 => 12345678901 is in group 10
19 => 1234567890123456789 is in group 10
20 => 12345678901234567890 is in group 20
21 => 123456789012345678901 is in group 20
```

---

After OP's update:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2136b7cb84a87f332b2fa9add4b48fef2c56bd9))

```
$strings=[9=>'123456789',10=>'1234567890',11=>'12345678901',19=>'1234567890123456789',20=>'12345678901234567890',21=>'123456789012345678901'];
foreach($strings as $k=>$str){
    echo "$k => $str is in group ",(floor(strlen($str)/10)+1)*10,"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
9 => 123456789 is in group 10
10 => 1234567890 is in group 20
11 => 12345678901 is in group 20
19 => 1234567890123456789 is in group 20
20 => 12345678901234567890 is in group 30
21 => 123456789012345678901 is in group 30
```

Here is another method that delivers EXACTLY what the OP is asking for, but I bet it's "not right" either.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77effe7f68c389bafb1d104a49b7055873e7b038

Comment: am so sorry i dont really no how to explan my question but i just want on
    if(strlen($str) > 9) {
        echo 'the string is almost  20';
    }
    elseif(strlen($str) > 19) {
        echo 'the string is almost 30';
    }
    just thing of when the string is bigger than expected can i still achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question to specify exactly what outputs you would like for the test cases that I have provided.  you can even reference my demo link.  When I better understand your requirements, I can update my answer.

Comment: Your question update means there will never be a `10` group.  Is that what you want?  Do you want the `upto` group to be "under 20"?

Comment: Do you want this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2136b7cb84a87f332b2fa9add4b48fef2c56bd9 ?

Comment: i dont want in group i just want to get the next odd number after each 9 of the other characters in the string example 9 next 20 next 30 next 40

Comment: Your question is unclear please update your question to express exactly the desired result for each string in my array.  I will then be able to fix my answer.

Comment: This? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81d6886f5841e10a4e84a95b40dae3ea2d18815d

Comment: Please see the new link at the bottom of my answer.  If this not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: Am sorry see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824655/how-do-i-sort-this-in-one-line