# how do i sort this in one line

Tags: php, string, count

i have this string like:

```
  $te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';

  $text=strlen($te);
  if($text<=10)       
  { 
  echo '2';
  }
  if($text>=11) 
  {
  echo '4';
   }
  if($text>=19) 
  { 
  echo '6';
  }
  if($text>=29) 
  {
  echo '8'; 
  }
 if($text>=39) 
  { 
  echo '10'; 
  }
```

which other way can i do this in one line of code? Instead of too many (IF)?
Or how will i achieve this my expected output when the characters for $text is very large like upto hundred in characters

big thanks in advance

Comment: currently, if the count was 40, you would echo '46810' is that what you want?

Comment: not counting working with 9 after the other

Comment: like your previous question, no one really understands what you want.

Comment: Maybe in addition to your coding attempt, you could include a plain English explanation of your intended logic.  Because it is a bit mind boggling.

Comment: @mickmackusa i don't think the OP knows any English :(

Comment: I simply don't understand why the groups have different size ranges and awkward starting points.  Is there a good reason not to divide the groups evenly on `10`'s,

Comment: @examma could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: A song while we wait... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASZcqWTk3qY

Answer (score -1):

Before I bother with an explanation, I'll wait to hear if my (now fourth attempt) is correct...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2abb5d284bed98e69bd01e3cb443e87da543d1c3))

```
$strings=[9=>'123456789',10=>'1234567890',
          11=>'12345678901',18=>'123456789012345678',
          19=>'1234567890123456789',
          28=>'1234567890123456789012345678',
          38=>'12345678901234567890123456789012345678'];
foreach($strings as $k=>$str){
    echo "$k => $str: ",($len=strlen($str))<11 ? 2 :2*(floor(($len+1)/10)+1),"\n";
}
//0 - 10 : 1 2
//11 - 18 : 2 4
//19 - 28 : 3 6
//29 - 38 : 4 8
```

Output:

```
9 => 123456789: 2
10 => 1234567890: 2
11 => 12345678901: 4
18 => 123456789012345678: 4
19 => 1234567890123456789: 6
28 => 1234567890123456789012345678: 6
38 => 12345678901234567890123456789012345678: 8
```